# Routing v7/v8, bicycle and durations

Tags: here-api

I'm getting started on Here Routing API, and I noticed some differences for which I'd like some enlightments:

1. Why is bicycle transport mode available in v7 but not anymore in v8?
2. There are differences between v7 and v8 in duration values, with pedestrian transport mode for example... I don't understand the reason; maybe I am missing something?

   **v7:** `https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled;&waypoint0=geo!48.904732,2.30254&waypoint1=geo!48.872631,2.35753&transportMode=pedestrian&walkSpeed=1.4` *=> duration 1h11min*

   **v8:** `https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=pedestrian&origin=48.904732,2.30254&destination=48.872631,2.35753&return=summary` *=> duration 1h39min*

At first glance the v7 seems more appropriate to my needs, but I wouldn't like to implement a service that will be deprecated in a few months, as I guess the v8 will soon replace v7, isn't it?

These questions (bicycle transport mode and duration differences) are important for my project, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1st Q: bicycle routing mode is currently being ported from V7 to V8. It will be officially supported pretty soon, maybe early July.

Answer to 2nd Q: the difference is due to the walkSpeed parameter used in V7. If you remove the parameter, you will get almost the same duration. Currently, V8 doesn't support the parameter. But, a new "pedestrian[speed]" parameter is currently under work and will available soon, likely in July as well.

Actually V7 is still being actively maintained, new features are also being scheduled till year end. So, it is not likely to phase out anytime soon. Hopefully, these answered your questions.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! For now, I guess that API version will be decided (for my project) according to feature schedule. And I'll be waiting for the v8 updates! Thx again for your answer, and for all the work Here is making.

Comment: Oh and btw, public transport will be available also on v8 soon? Thx !