# Does the HERE API v8 support bicycle routing?

Tags: here-api

I was wondering if the HERE API supports bicycle routing in version 8 as of now? I can see from a previous answer ([Routing v7/v8, bicycle and durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518002/routing-v7-v8-bicycle-and-durations)), that it is on its way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. You can check the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.6.4/api-reference-swagger.html), which will updated when the API is updated.